Image not aligned properly in card grid

Im using UIkit to create a grid of news items.
The responsiveness works great, but in large screens the image is not aligned properly.
However I don't seem to succeed in getting the image aligned to the left like this:
Correct:

Wrong:

The image stays on the top left corner.
What can I add to make it like this? (open the snippet in full screen)
This is my code:


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.4/css/uikit.almost-flat.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-grid uk-child-width-1-1 uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-3@l uk-child-width-1-1@xl uk-grid-match" uk-grid>
                <div>
                    <div class="el-item uk-grid-item-match">
                        <a class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-hover uk-transition-toggle uk-flex uk-flex-column uk-flex-stretch uk-link-toggle" href="#" uk-scroll>
                            <div class="uk-grid-collapse uk-flex-1 uk-flex-column  uk-flex-row@xl" uk-grid>
                                <div class="uk-width-1-3@xl uk-flex uk-flex-1  uk-flex-none@xl">
                                    <div class="uk-card-media-left uk-flex uk-flex-1 uk-flex-initial@xl" uk-toggle="cls: uk-card-media-left uk-card-media-top; mode: media; media: @xl">

                                        <div class="uk-inline-clip uk-height-1-1 uk-flex">
                                            <picture>
                                                <img src="https://mydstnytest.dstnydev.nl/component/ajax/?p=image&src=%7B%22file%22%3A%22images%2Fheaders%2Fheader_mydestiny_01.jpg%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22webp%2C85%22%2C%22thumbnail%22%3A%22%2C%2C%22%7D&hash=f199aa23" width="1920" height="1280" alt loading="lazy" class="el-image uk-transition-scale-up uk-transition-opaque uk-object-cover uk-height-1-1">
                                            </picture>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="uk-width-expand uk-flex-none  uk-flex-1@xl">

                                    <div class="uk-card-body uk-margin-remove-first-child">

                                        <h3 class="el-title uk-h4 uk-margin-top uk-margin-remove-bottom">                        <span class="uk-link-heading">Aantrekkelijke eindejaarspromotie Eurofiber</span>                    </h3>
                                        <div class="el-meta uk-text-meta uk-margin-small-top">9-11-2024</div>

                                        <div class="el-content uk-panel uk-margin-small-top"><p>Tot 31 december krijg je een aantrekkelijke korting op Eurofiber glasvezelverbindingen ban 200Mbps ...</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



